# SQL Split One Row To Multiple Rows Based on Column Number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an order table and I will keep it simple. I need to split the rows based on the quantity in the order. For example, if an order quantity is 4 I need to split the original rows into 4 rows with quantity of 1 each. Example data below.

```
ID     FKID     Product     QTY
1      100      Widget      4
```

I need a result like this.

```
 ID     FKID     Product     QTY
 1       100      Widget      1
 2       100      Widget      1
 3       100      Widget      1
 4       100      Widget      1
```

Comment: HOw high could `QTY` go?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One simple method is a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select  ID, FKID, Product, QTY
      from t
      union all
      select  ID, FKID, Product, QTY - 1
      from t
      where qty > 1
     )
select id, fkid, product, 1 as qty
from cte;
```

The only caveat is that if `qty` can be 100 or greater, you'll need `option (maxrecursion 0)`.

Comment: Note that if you *are* going to have much higher numbers, an rCTE is going to be far slower, that a non-iterative method. If it's going to be <=10, or even 100, and the data sets small, the difference will be negligible.

Comment: I think this will do it. I establish the base column and then split X times as I need. Not sure if the quantity will exceed 100. I will have to look at the production data. But I don't think it will go that high. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Just another option using an ad-hoc tally table and a simple JOIN

**Example**

```
Select ID = row_number() over (partition by A.ID order by N)
      ,FKID
      ,Product
      ,Qty = 1
 From  YourTable A
 Join (
        Select Top (1000) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) 
         From  master..spt_values n1 ,master..spt_values n2 
      ) B on N<=A.[QTY]
```

**Returns**

```
ID  FKID    Product Qty
1   100     Widget  1
2   100     Widget  1
3   100     Widget  1
4   100     Widget  1
```